# How to remove active class when scroll page

Tags: javascript

In Udacity's Landing Page Project They Requested To Add an active state to my navigation items when a section is in the viewport.
My code gives links active class successfully
but not removing it
This Is Code On GitHub:
https://github.com/BasemAmr/Udacity-FEND-Landing-PageProject/blob/master/js/app.js
And Page Preview:
https://basemamr.github.io/Udacity-FEND-Landing-PageProject/

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns in array and I saw here `const links = document.querySelectorAll('menu__link');` you didn't index on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is how you're selecting your `menu_link` elements. On line 108, you're doing

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll('menu__link');
```

which is replicating what you did in the previous part of the function, but `querySelectorAll()` expects a selector, in this case, a class name. and class names ***must*** be prefixed with a `.` character. This will fix your issue:

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.menu__link');
```

The rest of your code seems to work just fine.